# Add reference to older DLL in .NET Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, reference

I am trying to add a reference to a file from army.mil, corpscon_v6.dll, to my .NET project.

When adding the file, it states: 'corpscon_v6.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.' Next, I ran Dependency Walker and found two problems inside the DLL: IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL cannot be found. I have searched for these DLL's and it seems they aren't needed. I'm also afraid to go downloading any kind of DLL's like this from a miscellaneous site because I can't trust them, and many sites are saying to not do this.

Next, I ran tlbimp.exe to convert the DLL, but this didn't work either. This comes back with an error: The input file 'c:\temp\corpscon_v6.dll' is not a valid type library. I also tried doing a regsvr32 on it but this comes back with an 'entry point not found error.' Considering the time I have spent dealing with the completely broken Army Corps website, I am at a complete wall with how to get their grandiose CORPSCON DLL working in my project/

Comment: That's not going to work, you will have to use pinvoke.  The site is down so hard to help you.  There are sample declarations [available here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1948435.html) but they are VB6 declarations that you'll have to convert to VB.NET.  Long = Integer.

Comment: YOU SAVED THE DAY! After I changed the datatypes from long to int, it worked! Thank you so much for your help I've been so frustrated and now it's over! :)

Comment: I had NO idea to use PInvoke. After you sent me that link, I tried the code in it and no success. So then I started researching the error I was getting from that code and found someone who said it worked after they switched the data type. I still don't know what PInvoke is LOL...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. It all works for me up to the point of retrieving the answer.
Maybe you can figure out what this old man does not know about C stuff.
Good Luck

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

```
<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetInSystem", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetInSystem(ByVal InValue As Integer) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function


<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetInDatum", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function setindatum(ByVal InValue As Int16) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function
<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetOutDatum", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetOutDatum(ByVal InValue As Int32) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function

<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetOutSystem", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetOutSystem(ByVal InValue As Int32) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function



<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="Corpscon_initialize", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function Corpscon_initialize() As Double
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function


<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="GetXOut", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function GetXOut() As Double
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function


<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetOutZone", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetOutZone(ByVal InValue As Int32) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function

<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetXIn", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetXIn(ByVal InValue As Double) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function


<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetYIn", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetYIn(ByVal InValue As Double) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function

<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="corpscon_initialize_convert", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function corpscon_initialize_convert() As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function

<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="SetOutUnits", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function SetOutUnits(ByVal InValue As Int32) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function

<DllImport("c:\Develop\CorpsCon\corpscon_v6.dll", EntryPoint:="GetYOut", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function GetYOut() As Double
    ' Leave function empty - DllImport attribute forces calls   
    ' to Corpsconconfig to be forwarded to MoveFileW in KERNEL32.DLL.  
End Function



Public Sub convertDegreestoMeters(ByVal inx As Double, ByVal iny As Double, ByRef outx As Double, ByRef outy As Double)
    Dim RetVal As Integer

    RetVal = SetInSystem(1)
    RetVal = setindatum(1983)
    RetVal = SetOutSystem(2)
    RetVal = SetOutDatum(1983)
    RetVal = setoutzone(2301)
    RetVal = setoutUnits(3)  '1=US Servey Foot, 2=International Foor,3=Meters

    RetVal = corpscon_initialize_convert()

    RetVal = SetYIn(iny)
    RetVal = SetXIn(inx)
    Dim script As String

    RetVal = corpscon_initialize_convert()

    Dim outdbl As Double
    outdbl = GetXOut()
    script = "<script language=JavaScript>window.alert('" & outdbl & "'); </script>"
    'ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "tab3", script)  
    outx = outdbl

    outdbl = GetYOut()
    script = "<script language=JavaScript>window.alert('" & outdbl & "'); </script>"
    'ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "tab4", script)  
    outy = outdbl

End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim outx As Double = 0
    Dim outy As Double = 0
    Call convertDegreestoMeters(CDbl(88.5555), CDbl(27.5555), outx, outy)
    'Results SHOULD BE Outx=
End Sub
```

End Module